# how big would a "typical" Salesforce installation/configuration code base be, in lines of code?

Tags: salesforce

I understand that "lines of code" may be not a fully accurate measurement standard because a lot of Salesforce configuration might be done through a gui. Nevertheless, for the sake of argument, let's say that either each config field manually filled out in the gui is like a line of code, or else let's imagine the configuration being done entirely in source code, if Force platforms allows it.

Well, so, how big would a typical "professional" or "enterprise" level Salesforce installation code base be? Is it like 1K lines? 10K lines? Are there many 100K and more cases out there?

Comment: This really doesn't mean anything at all — for staters you don't install it, it's a cloud based service, so the size of the metadata (the configuration stored as xml) is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: of course it's relevant. It doesn't matter where config data and Apex code is stored - what matters is the inherent complexity of the deployment, which in part can be measured in the size of the code base and config files.

Comment: You're asking for something completely intangible though — what is a typical setup? Many would argue that would be out of the box setup with very few changes, for others it can involve many custom objects, layouts, workflows, profiles etc. There is no way to put any number on this that would allow you to draw any meaningful comparison to any other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will hardly get a meaningful answer. Just as an example, one of my clients is an ISP, we've been at their enterprise instance for 5 years now and we have a code base of about 600KB (+testing code to satisfy 75% requirement) with more than 100 classes and even more pages, about 20 custom tabs, 30 custom objects and appx 150 custom fields on factory objects, all that complemented by a ton of work done on administrative customization. In contrast, their sister company operating the same business in another territory has its own instance without a single line of code, but they use it just for opportunity tracking and do their provisioning, operations, case mgmt and other stuff from different (legacy) systems.

The overall average statistics is something that salesforce only knows and they don't seem to be sharing that info. Either way you should get a trial of whatever instance you want and see what is missing in terms of your business requirements and plan accordingly.